# pass struct array to a function by reference

Tags: c++

there have been a lot of resources on this but I could not really understand the concept of this.

Here is my attempt using pointers:

```
struct PEOPLE{
   int id;
   string name;
   float cash;
};

int main(){
   PEOPLE data[5];
   getdata(data);

   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      cout << data[i].id << " " << data[i].name << "  " << data[i].cash;
   }
   return 0;
}

void getdata(PEOPLE &*refdata[5]){
    refdata[0].id = 11;
    refdata[0].name = "John Smith";
    refdata[0].cash = 200.30;
    //and so on for index 1,2,3,4
}
```

Is this approach correct, I doubt it will work.

Comment: Shouldn't the structure definition end with a semicolon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for arrays of a size known at compile time:

```
template<size_t N >
void getdata(PEOPLE (&refdata)[N] )
{
   refdata[0] = ....;
}
```

To restrict to size 5,

```
void getdata(PEOPLE (&refdata)[5] )
{
   refdata[0] = ....;
}
```

Comment: @edward That happens to be the required syntax for passing a (non-const) reference to a fixed size array. I must admit that doesn't make much sense to me, but the idea is to distinguish between a reference to an array and an array of references.

Comment: thanks for your help, one more q, when i pass by reference, should I do like this `getdata(data);` or this `getdata(data[5]);`?

Comment: @edward Use `getdata(data);`. `getdata(data[5])` passes a single (invalid) element to the function. It is actually an out of bounds array access.

Comment: But the question still remains: why would you ever do this? Arrays already decay into pointers; passing by reference doesn't bring much benefits, and it just causes confusion...

Comment: @H2CO3 because it restricts it to a certain size, and you don't have to pass the size as a second parameter (second case), and it gives you a handle on the size in the function template case. It is making use of compile-time information lost when an array is allowed to decay into a pointer.

Comment: is there a better way to do this? since I need a function to manually input values for the array since the logic will be repeated, instead of repating the logic in main, i will only need to do the logic once in a function then call it repeatly in main when needed.

Comment: @juanchopanza , so my function identifier `int getdata(PEOPLE &);`, is this correct? it seems to be not working for me.

Comment: @edward that would take a single `PEOPLE` instance by reference. I cannot say whether it is correct or not, but it does not take a reference to an array as you required.

Comment: @juanchopanza so how do i write the function identifier to take a reference to an array?

Comment: @edward just like I said in my answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza that's only true when the size is known to be invariant at design time; not sure if it is the case here.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, of course. I would suggest a two-iterator solution for the more general case, but now I am not convinced it is necessary to pass a range or an array at all.

Comment: @juanchopanza , unfortunately, I faced an error when debug: ` binary '[' : 'data' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`

Comment: it seems to be happening at when i am printing out the array data[i]

Comment: oh my bad, i accidentally removed the [5] from `PEOPLE data[5];`

Comment: @juanchopanza Surely, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define it as:

```
void getdata(PEOPLE refdata[])
```

and call:

```
 getdata(data);
```